# Need help with reading schematics for the PC Engine console

Tags: schematics

Problem: console works with power supply, but doesn't turn on with external power to exp. port on the back (has two pins for Vin)

Could not find the proper pc engine manual, but tg16 should be similar. On the last page there is EXTPOW section. I just can't find how the contact "CN104 3" is connected.

Manual link:
http://archives.tg-16.com/MISC/TurboGrafx-16-Service-Manual.pdf

Comment: Is there a DC plug with a built in switch? So it should work if DC plug is unplugged?

Comment: Is anything plugged into the expansion port? Is the switch itself faulty?

Comment: There is a DC plug, as seen on the scheme, it works with the switch. The console itself is plugged into "interface unit (needed for cd addon)", which is supplying power to console via Vin inputs CN103 11/14R (I checked the voltage) and as I seen on the internet, console should turn on automatically without using switch.

Comment: https://gamesx.com/misctech/pcebp.php description of the exp port